# output of grep to include output of the searched file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, diff

I have been trying to find a way to do comparisons of files with grep where I also have the output of the first file I am trying to compare.

The files I have are lists of plugins for Jenkins, and I am trying to quickly compile a list of differences between all of the instances of Jenkins.  The output of the Jenkins command line gives a short name, long name, plugin version.  So the format is something in the line of:

```
SupPlugin SuperPlugin 1.6 (1.8)
```

I have about 8 Jenkins instances, and can pull the list of plugins.  What I need to do is find inconsistencies in which plugins are installed.  I have been toying with grep and diff to try and pull out what I need and store it so I can look at it and update the servers where needed.

The grep command I have is

```
grep -v output1.txt output2.txt output3.txt > list.txt
```

The issue I have with this is that while this gives an output of 1 compared to 2 and 1 compared to 3, it does not output what 1 was.  I wanted to get the output of the current line in grep when it finds a mismatch, so basically I want to get a list from 1 as well as 2 and 3 so I can compare versions.

I've also been trying to use diff and loop through each file to create a diff.  Since these are essentially sets, I figure if I do end up trying to use a diff I will have to loop 1 against the rest, then 2 against the rest, then 3, ect... until I have created a file that has all of the differences, but then I will need to process that file to remove duplicates and change the format to be a bit more readable.

Is there a way to get grep to do what I am thinking of, or a better way to use diff to get the result I'm trying to get?

Comment: (Not sure why "grep" is involved (your grep line is missing a regex.) If you just want to see if the files are out of sync, you could do something like :

sum output1.txt output2.txt output3.txt

If all the checksums are the same, it's very likely that the files are the same. Could be a good first pass?)

Comment: I don't need to know if the files are the same or not, as I know there is going to be differences.  What I need is a list of the differences along with what was different from the original file I'm comparing.  grep actually gives me most of the output I would want, but does not include the output from output1.txt.  So I get the differences found in 2 and 3 from 1, but not the line from 1 that was different.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about the content of the files you want to compare but 'sdiff -s' prints the difference of two files, here the syntax:

```
$ sdiff -s file1 file2
```

Hope this helps,